# Custom memory allocation in wxWidgets

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, wxwidgets

Is there a way to use custom allocators for ALL of wxWidgets? As in it always grabs memory from a certain memory allocator? I have not found any topics on this in the past and I don't see a way through the documentation to have this. If there is, could someone please provide an example of how to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to overload the global new and delete. At least that is what wxWidgets internally uses when you enable [debugging](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_debuggingoverview.html) memory.

But there might be some [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2104459/79455) with that.

You can also just edit the wxWidgets source to use your own allocators by overloading new and delete as they do in [wx/memory.h](http://svn.wxwidgets.org/viewvc/wx/wxWidgets/trunk/include/wx/memory.h?revision=71102&view=markup)